# Find the volume of a 3-dimensional body

Tags: calculus

The base of S is an elliptical region with boundary curve $25x^2+16y^2=400$. Cross-sections perpendicular to the x-axis are isosceles right triangles with hypotenuse in the base.

i got 400/3

my work http://puu.sh/6BPTe

[image: picture]

is this correct?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, your answer is fine!

This is because the area of an isosceles right triangle with hypotenuse on the base has area equal to $\displaystyle \frac{1}{2}h^2$, and when isolating $y$, you multiply the length of the hypotenuse by $2$ to compensate for the entire ellipse.

Answer (score 0):

(aiming for this question to have an answer)

Looks fine to me (except for the $l$ and $y$ not written as maths where they are first defined ;) ).